# How to print the grails controller params object values in Aop

Tags: spring, grails, spring-aop

I have a controller in that the **params** object consists of id, username, max and offset values.

I am trying to access the **params** object in Aop but it is giving me the default length and the class parameters only.

I tried accessing in different ways but unable to access the **params** values

Controller ::

```
class UserController {
    def index() {
        params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 5, 100)
        params.offset = params.offset ? params.offset.toInteger() : 0;
        User user = User.findById(params.id);
        ------
        -----
        ----
    }
}
```

AOP code ::

```
@Aspect
class LogInterceptor {

private static final logger = LogFactory.getLog(this)

@Before("within(com.sample..*)")
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

    String msg = String.format("logBefore : %s.%s(%s)",
            joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName(),
            joinPoint.getSignature().getName(),
            Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));

    logger.info(msg);
}
}
```

How to access the values id, username and other parameters

Log for the above code ::

2014-11-13 16:28:10,722 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] INFO  aop.LogInterceptor  - logBefore : com.sample.controller.UserController.getMetaClass([])

2014-11-13 16:28:10,722 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] INFO  aop.LogInterceptor  - logBefore : com.sample.controller.UserController.getMetaClass([])

2014-11-13 16:28:10,723 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] INFO  aop.LogInterceptor  - logBefore : com.sample.controller.UserController.getProperty([**params**])

2014-11-13 16:28:10,724 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] INFO  aop.LogInterceptor  - logBefore : com.sample.controller.UserController.index([])

2014-11-13 16:28:10,727 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] INFO  aop.LogInterceptor  - logBefore : com.sample.service.UserService.getMetaClass([])

In the third line am getting the params but I need the inner values of it

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don's see where you are accessing the desired `controller's params` object.

Comment: I modified the question and added the log. When I call the **joinPoint.getArgs()**, it gives me the **params** object

Comment: how the `joinPoint.args` is filled in?

Comment: joinPoint.args will give the input params of that method and that is filled by the AOP.

Comment: `params` is not a controller method's argument, it's a class field. You should rethink your approach. Are you sure, you HAVE to use the old-fashioned AOP crap here? Grails provides simple and clean ways to intercept methods

Comment: I am new to the grails.. I saw the Interceptors in grails documentation(http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#interceptors) but we have to write for every class..
I don't know exact terms in grails.. but I want a AOP kind of thing where I can log the class name , method name and the input parameters..etc
I am able to print all the things excepts these arguments.. please guide how to access these things

Comment: This question is quite peculiar.  The question almost doesn't match with the code that is described as an attempt.  An answer below describes a reasonable way to do something that the question might have intended to express, then the OP responded with new requirements related to services that are not present in the question.  I can't make sense of much of this.

Comment: I tried different way's but I didn't attached the code. 
Actually I need to implement the loggers from a single point like AOP, because In AOP only we can apply the loggers for the complete flow(Controller layer -> service layer -> helper class).. so I implemented it and in that am unable to access the params object. Is there any way to access the **params** object in AOP classes

Comment: Why does it have to be AOP? The request parameters shouldn't be changing during the request processing (as a controller invokes a service method etc.)?  Can you just define a simple Grails filter and log the request parameters there?

Comment: Are you trying to log the HTTP request parameters or any parameters passed to any method?

Comment: I have a requirement to send only few parameters to the service layer... 

And my helper class does not need all the parameters from service layer... 

Now I want to log the flow of what parameters are been send to each layer...

This has been implemented the same in Spring Project.. but not sure how to do in Grails 

HTTP request parameters and any parameters passed to any method

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: "HTTP request parameters and any parameters passed to any method." - You aren't going to be able to do that.  AOP is not going to help you log parameters to any method. The logging will only happen when invoking methods on the AOP proxy and there are loads of invocations that won't fall in that category.  This question really should be closed.  There are a number of confusing aspects to it that are just consuming people's time.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case you can use the `controller interceptors` from your [link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#interceptors):

```
class UserController {
  def index() {
  }

  def afterInterceptor = {
    log.debug "action:$actionName -> $params"
  }
}
```

However if you need to apply the same interceptor to multiple controllers, you can either inherit the base class with the interceptor, or use the [Filters](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters)

```
class LoggingFilters {

  def filters = {
    logging(controller:'*', action:'*') {
      after = {
        log.debug "controller:$controllerName action:$actionName -> $params"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This will log only the controllers but I have a scenario where the request travels from controller layer to service layer to helper method then the log for the service layer and helper method will not work.. I think

Comment: well, your original question relates to controllers only

Comment: apologize for the ambiguity.. 
Actually I need to implement the loggers from a single point like AOP, because In AOP only we can apply the loggers for the complete flow(Controller layer -> service layer -> helper class).. 
so I implemented it and in that am unable to access the **params** object. 
So I need help in accessing the **params** object in AOP classes .